# python - delete line if invalid character

Tags: python, regex, md5

I have a 2GB .txt file that has over 60 million lines of what should be MD5 hash values. I've been having problems importing it into a piece of software due to an 'arithmetic error' and so before, I removed any lines that didn't contain 32 characters (to represent the MD5 hash length). Nonetheless, the problem has persisted.

Having reviewed the document manually, some lines don't indeed contain valid hash values. Therefore, I'm looking to read every line and if it contains values other than those between 0-9 and A-F, I'd like the line removed.

I anticipate that Regex may be required but unsure.

I'm just after some pointers on how to implement this string validation? As said, each line should only contain characters between 0-9 and A-F (hexademical).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import re
import sys
import fileinput


md5_checker = re.compile("^[a-fA-F0-9]{32}$")

for line in fileinput.input():
    if md5_checker.match(line):
        sys.stdout.write(line)
    else:
        sys.stderr.write("INVALID: %s" % line)
```

Usage:

```
$ cat testfile.txt 
0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
92eb5ffee6ae2fec3ad71c777531578f
asdf
0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
92eb5ffee6ae2fec3ad71c777531578f

$ python ~/Desktop/md5_checker.py testfile.txt > cleaned.txt
INVALID: asdf

$ cat cleaned.txt 
0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
92eb5ffee6ae2fec3ad71c777531578f
0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
92eb5ffee6ae2fec3ad71c777531578f
```

**Warning**: don't read and write to the same file (`md5_checker testfile.txt > testfile.txt` will wipe the file!)

Answer (score 3):

A possible regex would be, which would of course also possibly match on other things. However, it does check for only characters A-F and numbers 0-9.

```
r'^[A-F\d]+$'
```

You could easily add `{32}` to also check for length, but you say that you've already cleaned any non-32 length lines out, it doesn't matter (and for someone new to regexes, only obscure things unnecessarily). For reference, it would then look like this:

```
r'^[A-F\d]{32}+$'
```

You'd simply read the file in, line by line and match on the regex. If it is a match, add it to the output file.

For more information on the Python re module, check this out http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Comment: That matches on other things than valid MD5 hashes.

Comment: Or `r'^[A-F0-9]{32}$' to include the length.

Comment: A md5 fingerprint is always 128bits long (32 hex characters). You can safely use `r'^[a-fA-F\d]{32}'`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match) with the proper regular expression.

```
import re

r = re.compile(r'^[a-fA-F0-9]{32}$')

with open("hashes") as i, open("hashes_cleaned", "w") as o:
    for line in i:
        # Cheap check for 32 chars, first.
        if len(line.strip()) == 32 and r.match(line.strip()):
            o.write(line)
```

**Example**

Input:

```
% cat hashes
c2cf0d7b2d3c5cd91a1314a2285ce53e
12524f7af3a5dad467264683d0ec6206
746518a1c63294d367c23cab37f4166c
foo
4d6deee14efe78180c698679e16f7342
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
eb9a25b6b525ae665115b43a259d2355
```

Output:

```
% cat hashes_cleaned 
c2cf0d7b2d3c5cd91a1314a2285ce53e
12524f7af3a5dad467264683d0ec6206
746518a1c63294d367c23cab37f4166c
4d6deee14efe78180c698679e16f7342
eb9a25b6b525ae665115b43a259d2355
```

Comment: he specifically says he does not want lines containing smaller case letters ;/

Comment: @eakron No, he says he want's to check for valid MD5 hashes. Lower case letters `a`-`f` are legal for this, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use re to parse the line. 
Try this code:

```
import re
match = re.match('[0-9A-F]{32}', line)
if match:
    #valid line
else:
    #invalid line
```

Comment: What about lower case letters `a` to `f`?

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution without using regex

```
import string
#create a set of all possible hex digits.
#in case you want only upper case hex letters, 
#convert to upper
hexchars = set(string.hexdigits.upper())
#iterate through your file
for line in somefile:
    #See if there is any chars apart from the hex char set
    if set(line) - set(hexchars):
        print "Some Invalid Message"
    else:
        #Do something useful
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep '[A-Fa-f\d]{32}' filename.txt >newfilename.txt if you have access to terminal.
```